# How do I make the background color cover my entire DIV and not just the text in it?

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I have a DIV that contains image and text ...

```
<div id="control" class="btn">

<div id="btn_container"><img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minecraft-icons/512/Stone_Pickaxe.png" alt="Mining pick" /></div>

<span>Start</span> 

</div>
```

I would like to have a background color in my DIV, so I did this

```
.btn
{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background:gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but the background color is only appearing on my image and not in the DIV -- https://jsfiddle.net/xwdnvcy5/17/ .  How do I make the background color appear in the entirety of the DIV?  I would prefer not to hard-code a height and width in my DIV as I plan to use this class for other elements.

Comment: could you show in image how do you want it to appear.

Comment: @satish, please consider upvote the useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the absolutely positioned img, I've modified the link. 
If you want to move around the elements make the text span relative.
https://jsfiddle.net/sandeepcnath/xwdnvcy5/19/

The reason for your issue is that absolutely positioned elements don't take up space in the layout. Only the text span was getting bg-color because it was the only element inside .btn occupying space.

```
.btn
{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background:gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#btn_container
{
}

.btn img
{

}


.btn span
{
    display:-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `div#btn_container` don't have any size because the `<img>` inside has an `absolute` positioning

position: **absolute**

> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout...

Read more about `position` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

One possible solution is removing the `.btn img` position property.
In this scenario it will set to `static` by default (Keep in mind that `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, and `z-index` properties have no effect when `position: static` and that's why I comment those in the code snippet bellow. I also removed the *margins* to keep the image inside the container `<div>`):

```css
.btn
{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background:gray;
    display: inline-block;
}

#btn_container
{
    border-radius:5px;
    background:red;
    position: relative;
}

.btn img
{
    /* static psoitioning don't care about position props like:
    left: 50%; top: 50%;*/
    /* remove margins to keep image inside the container div
    margin-left: -15px; margin-top: -15px;*/
    /*position: absolute;*/ /* line removed */
}

.btn span
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="control" class="btn">
  <div id="btn_container">
      <img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minecraft-icons/512/Stone_Pickaxe.png" alt="Mining pick" />
  </div>
  <span>Start</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the position: absolute on the .btn img that will help - I just played around with it to see.